# How to solve with FEM a semilinear elliptic equation?

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, na.numerical-analysis, numerical-analysis-of-pde, difference-equations, finite-element-method

I searched in many books regarding FEM how to solve semilinear elliptic equation, but I did not find too many things. They mostly treat linear and simple problems. For example in **P.Ciarlet-The finite element method for elliptic problems** at the last page there is a reference to some old work of Kakuchi (1976)(https://jaxa.repo.nii.ac.jp/records/34520) from which I do not understand too good.

Is there a resource/editable code that solves for example:

$$
\begin{cases} -\Delta u=u(c(x)-u),\ x\in\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^2 \\ \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial\nu}=0, x\in\partial\Omega\end{cases}
$$

?
Suppose that $c$ is taken so that the problem has a unique nontrivial and positive solution, like $c\equiv 1$.

Even the variational formulation is not standard $a(u,v)=\int_{\Omega}\nabla u\nabla v\ dx=\int_{\Omega}uv(c(x)-u)\ dx=b_u(v),\ \forall\ v\in H^1(\Omega)$.

Is there some literature about this topic? It looks like a very simple problem but I do not know how can I approach it. Finite differences lead to nonlinear systems of equations and Finite element seems to be unapplicable...how can we proceed?

Comment: You may need some premises like the existence/uniqueness of the solution $u\in H^1$, for some cases, you can use certain energy estimate + convexity + comparison principle to show a unique weak solution exists. Evans or Gilbarg-Trudinger books should have some discussions. 
Then one way to solve can be linearizing the problem and construct the solution using a sequence $u_{k}$ that 

$$a(u_{k+1}, v) = \int_{\Omega} \nabla u \cdot \nabla v - (c(x) - u_k(x)) u v = 0$$

As long as you can show this process converges, for instance, by certain monotonicity, then you can get a solution.